# Comparison operation - Correct Syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comparison, operators, jslint

Coming from PHP I understand the difference in using == verses === in a comparison operation, but with JavaScript is it acceptable to use == or ===?

I wanted to validate my JavaScript code and found [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). While running the validation with JSLint I see these types of messages.

Some examples:

```
var show = $('input[name=female]:checked').val() == "true";
```

- Problem at line 278 character 70: Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.

and

```
var show = $('input[name=living]:checked').val() != "false";
```

- Problem at line 283 character 38: Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.

So My question is, Would using the current syntax of == or != be valid/correct or do I need to use === and !== ?

EDIT: Just to point out the code does work

Comment: That’s not a syntax error but might be a semantic vagueness.

Comment: @Gumbo, Adding this to my vocab "semantic vagueness" +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct in a way but JSLint expects strict comparison to prevent problems with type conversion.

It is good practice to always use strict comparison and "normal" comparison only where you really need/want it (because you want to make use of type conversion for some reason).

From JSLint's [documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> ### == and !=
>
> The `==` and `!=` operators do type
>   coercion before comparing. This is bad
>   because it causes `' \t\r\n' == 0` to
>   be `true`. This can mask type errors.
>
> If you only care that a value is
>   *truthy* or *falsy*, then use the short
>   form. Instead of
>
> ```
> (foo != 0)
> ```
>
> just say
>
> ```
> (foo)
> ```
>
> and instead of
>
> ```
> (foo == 0)
> ```
>
> say
>
> ```
> (!foo)
> ```
>
> Always use the `===` and `!==`
>   operators.

Comment: Nice tip on the newline/tab shorthand characters

Answer (score 2):

Crockford and JSLint are somewhat dogmatic on this point, and I think over-prescriptive. Always using `===` rather than `==` is a reasonable rule of thumb for inexperienced JavaScript developers, but if you know the basic rules then there is no problem with using `==`. In particular, if the two operands are guaranteed to be of the same type (such as in a `typeof` comparison like `typeof foo == "undefined"`) then the two operators are specified to follow precisely the same steps.

There is also a reasonable point about habitually using `===` removing the need to think about which operator to use, but frankly I prefer to be forced to consider all the possible values of the two operands I'm comparing and find JSLint unnecessarily nannying.

Comment: LOL "JSLint unnecessarily nannying"

Answer (score 1):

The == syntax is valid but in some cases it can lead to rather nasty bugs in large projects. If you don't have a good reason to use == you should by default write JavaScript with === because it checks for type as you know.

It works either way, but you will save yourself pain in the future if you default to ===.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the situation.

=== is often preferred because you won't have any false-positives that you might not have considered (it might also be slightly quicker in some implementations because it compares to less potential values, although I haven't checked that, just a thought, and the speed difference would be negligible).

== is often more convenient to cover many/all cases (if I'm not mistaken, jQuery doesn't pass JSLint because in some places the code intentionally uses == to cover a multitude of cases rather than testing each one individually).

Comment: Thanks, I had also wanted to ask about jQuery passing validation as well

Comment: If the two operands are of the same type then `===` and `==` are specified to perform precisely the same steps, so barring browser implementation oddities, there will be no performance advantage either way.

Comment: @Tim, that's my point, that if they're not of the same type === can perform faster by returning an immediate false, while == will perform type conversion.

Comment: That is likely true, but that part of your answer is vague and seems to be suggesting that `===` may always be faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can do just == and !=, I don't think there would be any problems with that.